# window.opener is null in safari on iPad

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, web-applications, safari

I am running a web application in which I am opening a **child window** from the **parent window**.
From child `window` I want to open a new link in parent `window` using the `window.opener` but the `opener` property of `window` object is null.
This works fine in

- Internet Explorer (ver. 11)
- Google Chrome
- Firefox
- Safari

The problem occurs only on **iPad** in **Safari**.
 The code snippet is as follow:

```
  window.opener.location.href = '../Default.aspx?ArgVal=' + bookOpenArgs + '&WindowName=' + sWindowName + '&UserId=' + sUserId + '&csl=y';
```

Comment: Why don't you try `window.open()`?

Comment: Another note from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener#Notes): _Windows Phone browser does not support window.opener (tested with Microsoft Edge 25.10586.36.0).  It is also not supported in IE if the opener is in a different security zone._. As per 2016/01/15

Comment: @evolutionxbox Because I have to open the new link in the parent window.

Comment: In the parent window? Do you mean the current tab? iOS doesn't have windows... I would then recommend `window.location.href = newUrl` instead.

Comment: Yes, current tab. @evolutionxbox

Comment: No it does work fine in IE 11, Chrome and Firefox. The issue occurs only on Safari in iPad. Even it works fine in Safari on windows 7 @Chay22

Comment: It doesn't matter if the current solution works in IE11, Chrome and Firefox. If you want it to work on Safari you can't use the current solution. Why not try `window.location`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yeah you are right, Let me try this now.

Comment: At the very least, you need a way of doing either solution depending on the platform.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112876/discussion-between-imran-khan-hunzai-and-evolutionxbox).